# Play a specific audio based on hovered image (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I'm supposed to have 5 animal images on the site, and whenever I hover over an animal, their characteristic sound plays. Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than using switch case?
This is what I have so far (works only for 1 animal):

HTML:

```
<img src="img/piggy.png" onmouseover="F1(this)">
```

JS:

```
function F1(img) { 
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a really solid base. If it were me I would do almost exactly what you are doing but set up an array with the list of available sound bites. Then, `onmouseover` pass in a number (0-5) and use that as the selector to choose which soundbyte plays.

```
var sounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4", "sound5"];

function playAudio(track) {
   audio.play(sounds[track]);
}
```

Hopefully that's clear/helpful. Otherwise, let me know and I'll be glad to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the sound to play embedded in the `img` tag's dataset :

```
<img src="img/piggy.png" data-sound='piggy.wav' onmouseover="playSound(this)">
```

```
function playSound(element) { 
  var audio = new Audio(element.dataset.sound);
  audio.play();
}
```

you may want to pre-load all of the audio files on page load